# Code partially not applied (but executed) when a dynamically merged pdf file is downloaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I build a PDF binder based on the path data inside a gridview. When looping through the grid is finished, the PDF is automatically downloaded. In case a file does not exists, I want this to be easily seen by exchanging the icon "PDF" by a crossed out icon "noPDF".
For some reason this works only for the 2 scenarios:

- All files exist (pdf is downloaded)
- None of the files exist and therefore no pdf is downloaded (changed icons are displayed)

If there are some files missing the binder is created correctly, but the icons are not replaced. I have no clue in which direction to investigate. Why is the gridview not rendered in case of the file being downloaded?

```
    public void Start_Merge(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();
        iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, Response.OutputStream);
        document.Open();
        // loop through every line in Gridview and get the path' to each pdf
        int missing = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < Gridview_Presion.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            Label Path = Gridview_Presion.Rows[row].FindControl("LabelPDFPath") as Label;
            string path = Path.Text;
            string filename = Convert.ToString(Gridview_Presion.Rows[row].Cells[14].Text);

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                PdfReader Reader = new PdfReader(path);
                readerList.Add(Reader);
                for (int i = 1; i <= Reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(Reader, i));
                }
                Reader.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                missing = missing + 1;
                Image img = Gridview_Presion.Rows[row].FindControl("img_Cert") as Image;
                img.ImageUrl = "img/NoPdf.png";
            }
        }
        string file;
        file = SALESID.Text + "_CertPres.pdf";
        if (missing > 0)
        {
            LabelMissingPresCerts.Text = Convert.ToString(missing) + " Certificates missing!";
            file = SALESID.Text + "_CertPres_incomplete.pdf";
            LB_ReportMissingPresCert.Visible = true;
        }
        if (missing != Gridview_Presion.Rows.Count)
        {
            document.Close();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file);
        }
        else
        {
            //* these operations are necessary to avoid the no-page-error in case no file is downloaded
            string NullPath = @"\\corp.root.int\dax-emea$\DAX\ES75\Documents\Prod\Public\blank.pdf";
            PdfReader Reader = new PdfReader(NullPath);
            Chapter Chapter = new Chapter("Null", 0);
            document.Add(Chapter);
            readerList.Add(Reader);
            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(Reader, 1));
            Reader.Close();
            document.Close();
            Response.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check your page load event, it it re-loads/re-binds the grid, then you not see the changes. Put your page load code to load up the GV in a if (!IsPostBack) {then code here to load + bind the gv}.

Comment: The Gridview isn't loaded during the page load and therefore a postback shouldn't do anything to it in my understanding It is bound on a LinkButton click